# Extract data for each district from a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mapping, spatial, shapefile

I have a matrix (331X301) at 0.1 degree resolution data encompassing entire India and a district level shapefile with districtName as an attribute. I generally extarct data for each district from the matrix raster in ArcGIS. Is there a way to extract the mean data (mean of all the 0.1 degree grids that fall in that district) for all district in Matlab?

Link for shapefile: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ajxh9oeoND9bhOcwrzoLfEqBUNUTOg

Link for data: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajxh9oeoND9bhOcva9i-ByW45YBwoA

Note: the data is 3 dimension-331x301x12.

Code that overlays the shapefile on the data is below:

However, the shapefile S has 2299 attributes, I could not extract value of z2 for each of these 2299 attributes

```
Reading the shapefile
S=shaperead('C:\shpfiles\india_adm3.shp');

%selecting the first month from the data of 321x321x12
z2= data(:,:,1)

%makking dummy coordinates for the data
x = linspace(67, 97, 301);
y = linspace(5, 38, 331);
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
y=flipud(y);

%Clipping the data to the coastlines
isin = inpolygon(x,y,S.X,S.Y);
z2(~isin) = NaN;


figure('color','w');

mx=geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', 'White');

contourf(x,y,z2,'LineColor','none');

hold on

displaying the shapefile
S1=shaperead('C:\shpfiles\india_adm3.shp','Attributes',{'BoundingBox'});

lon1 = [S1.X]';
lat1 = [S1.Y]';
plot(lon1,lat1,'Linewidth',2,'color',[0 0 0]);
```

Comment: What did you try? You can probably transform the shapefile to some sort of bitmap and multiply it with the rainfall matrix and then get the mean of _that_. But there isn't enough detail to provide a more substantial answer. See [ask] and [mcve] on details on how ask a question so that P(get_an_answer) is maximized

Comment: Can you send a 10x10 version of your data?

Comment: @Brethlosze  Please find the edited question with link to data

Comment: @HoriaComan: Please find the edited question with the code that I wrote. I failed to extract a value of z2 for each of the 2299 attributes of the shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Hence, you have essentially a set of 12 images...

You roughly can depict the 1st map (and following) as:

```
imshow(data(:,:,1),[0 400])
```

And the average as:

```
imshow(mean(data,3),[0 400])
```

But i am afraid you need something else?

By the way i cannot see the file contents in the first attachment

Comment: I already wrote a code that overlays the shapefile (in the first link on the data. I need to extract the data for each of he attributes of the shapefile.Please find the edited question with the code